# To bind the the data directly to mat-checkbox in angular

Tags: angular8

I have the following mat-checkbox and I am passing the value has as shown in the code

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="temperature" name="temperature" value='70' color="primary" [disabled] = "(!device) || humidity || pressure ||!(!cust_entry) || lesser ||equal || contain" disabled>Temperature</mat-checkbox>
```

This checkbox I am using inside the form whenver I post the data it is coming has in json response {"temperature":true} but I want like {"temperature":"70"}. I know we can use onclickevent but I have 20 checkboxes I can't able to do onclickevent for all checkboxes

Comment: yap, you can bind the data with **ngModel** attribute.

Comment: @SaisivaA can you show me one example

Comment: take one **ngModel** attribute for each checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/examples

> component.html

```
    <section class="example-section">
        <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="checked">Checked</mat-checkbox>
        <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="indeterminate">Indeterminate</mat-checkbox>
    </section>
```

> component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'checkbox-configurable-example',
  templateUrl: 'checkbox-configurable-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['checkbox-configurable-example.css'],
})
export class CheckboxConfigurableExample {
  checked = false;
  indeterminate = false;
}
```

Comment: see what you are telling we can give only bool values not string values (like checked="hello")

Comment: No, I am getting only boolean values not string values i want to get string values the value the I pass